# Add same function to multiple same name div IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, slider

How can I add same function to multiple prev and next buttons on multiple sliders on the samge page? I've tried to loop trough every div named #prev and #next.

Script

```
function prevSlide() {
    if(count > 1) {
      count = count - 2;
      sliderList.style.left = '-' + count * sliderWidth + 'px';
      count++;
    }else if(count == 1) {
      count = items - 1;
      sliderList.style.left = '-' + count * sliderWidth + 'px';
      count++;
    }
    
  }
  function nextSlide() {
    if(count < items) {
      sliderList.style.left = '-' + count * sliderWidth + 'px';
      count++;
      
    }else if(count == items) {
      sliderList.style.left = '0px';
      count = 1;
      
    }
  }
  
     document.getElementById("prev").addEventListener('click', prevSlide); 

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
```

HTML prev and next buttons

```
 <div id="prev"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></div>
      <div id="next"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
```

Working code sample for better understanding

https://jsfiddle.net/ehvgLmxu/

Comment: IDs must be unique int he document, `$("#id")` and `doc.getElById(id)` will only ever get the first one.  Use classes.

Comment: Yes true. But when I use getElementsByClassName then the second prev and next buttons make the first slider slide to left and right.

Comment: The issue is really much deeper than just with the prev/next references, you have to change the way you think about the issue and about element references when making generic parts / components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the other answer says, you cannot use IDs, because they need to be unique on the page.There are also multiple other issues when trying to make your code generic.

I made an almost working example at https://jsfiddle.net/t248qymz/2/ - not perfect and has some bug with the `count`, but I hope the point comes across.

They key things to take away is: when you work with multiple instances of the same thing on your page, keep track of which element are you referring to. You always need to target the relevant ones in relation that what element was clicked. I recommend that you should get all of the element references from the event object (something like `e.target` or `e.currentTaget`) instead of caching them to variables.

Also, **please** format your code correctly before posting or continuing to code. It will help us and you - trust me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change id to class and then use the `getElementsByClassName()` function, it will return something called *nodeList*, and you can use the `forEach()` method on it. Which will loop over each element with the class name and do somethings with it.

Change to html to this:

```
<div class="prev"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></div>
<div class="next"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
```

```
function prevSlide() {
  if (count > 1) {
    count = count - 2;
    sliderList.style.left = '-' + count * sliderWidth + 'px';
    count++;
  } else if (count == 1) {
    count = items - 1;
    sliderList.style.left = '-' + count * sliderWidth + 'px';
    count++;
  }
}
function nextSlide() {
  if (count < items) {
    sliderList.style.left = '-' + count * sliderWidth + 'px';
    count++;

  } else if (count == items) {
    sliderList.style.left = '0px';
    count = 1;

  }
}

const prevBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('prev');
const nextBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('next');

prevBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', prevSlide));
nextBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', nextSlide));
```